# control may reach end of non-void function -wreturn-type

Tags: c, search, boolean

I am trying to create a short linear search algorithm but keep getting the error message **control may reach end of non-void function -wreturn-type**. I know that the error has to do with putting a return outside of the loop, but how do I get the return value from the loop then?

Here is the code:

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0; i<values[n]; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] == value)
        {
            printf("%i was found.", value);
            return true;
        }
        else if (values[i] != value)
        {
            printf("%i was not found.", value);
            return false;
        }
        else if (value <= 0)
        {
            printf("%i is not a positive number.", value);
            return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's supposed to be returned if `values[n]` is 0?

Comment: do you want to compare value with every element in values? then why do you return from function immediately?

Comment: inner `return false;` should be probably removed and only an outer one by placed.

Comment: Should not `for(int i=0; i<values[n]; i++)` --> `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`?

Answer (score 4):

The case when `0<values[n]` is false at the start of the function would result in the loop never being iterated over at all, and so control reaches the end.

Simple solution is to add `return false;` to the end of the function.

It looks to me like whatever the value, the loop will only ever have one iteration, so I don't think the code does what you want anyway. This is what I think you were intending. See how there is code outside of the loop, to be evaluated before the search and then after the search doesn't find anything. It's clear from the question that you need to look a bit more about the control flow of code, and what the return statement does.

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)
{
    if (value <= 0)
    {
        printf("%i is not a positive number.", value);
        return false;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (values[i] == value)
        {
            printf("%i was found.", value);
            return true;
        }
    }

    printf("%i was not found.", value);
    return false;
}
```